# How do I work with vim9 and unicode?

Tags: vimscript, unicode, vim9script

I've found myself in a bit of an interesting situation.

I'm writing a plugin in which I need to do a tiny bit of line parsing.

Given a file:

```
æøå
```

It's easy to verify that `col('.')` returns 1, 3, and 5 respectively. This is fine, I can work with this. Other unicode characters (or I guess anything expanding outside ascii) returns similar results: each character has an expanded length, `col('.')` is relative to the total string length.

In normal vimscript, with this specific use case in mind, I could:

```
fun! pndtest#Invoke()
    let line = getline('.')
    echoerr line[col('.') - 1]
endfun
```

(note: the autoload prefix is an arbitrary one I picked because I had a testbench ready. They have no practical meaning and are largely random)

`call pndtest#Invoke()` on one of the unicode characters, and get trash out because it's only half the character in this case. That's actually fine - in fact, this approach is what I used in vim9 and failed to use (this is my actual implementation by slightly butchered for the sake of an MCVE):

```
var position: number = col('.') - 1
var line = getline('.')
var i = position
var output = ""
while i >= 0
    var character = line[i]
    # in reality, there's other parsing here, but this is a simplification
    output = character .. output
    i -= len(character) # This did nothing, by the way. :')
endwhile
```

At the end of which, `output` should contain all the characters, unicode and otherwise, prior to the current position in the line.

This works fine in Vimscript, but not in vim9. Here's the exact same case as earlier:

```
vim9script

def pnd2test#Invoke()
    var line = getline('.')
    echoerr line[col('.') - 1]
enddef
```

Given the same file as presented at the start of this post, it doesn't echoerr trash - it echoerrs *the actual unicode character*.

While this is great because it means Vim is starting to do some unicode handling, this means `col()` is essentially useless because the strings are suddenly not indexable in the same way as they used to be. It works fine on the first column, but `getline('.')[1]` in the previously listed file is `ø`, not trash triggered by a partial character. You might see where this is going.

This means that `col('.')` would have to return 2 on `ø` for the code to work, not 3. The `å` would have to be 3, not 5. Unfortunately for me, this stacks. The more unicode characters in the line, the more the error propagates, and the worse the offset is, rendering my approach essentially useless.

And again, this is purely a vim9 thing - vimscript itself treats the characters appropriately relative to `col('.')`, presenting different but arguably more managable unicode-related problems (they can largely be solved by subtracting or adding the length of the individual character)

Just for the sake of visualizing the problem:
(note: the spaces used in the vimscript example represent the second byte of the character, NOT literal spaces)

```
VimScript:
String index: 01234
file        : æ ø å
Col index   : 1 3 5  # This is fine: subtract 1, the data is still continuous between the indices

Vim9:
String index: 012 
File        : æøå
Col index   : 135    # And this is the problem: complete mismatch with the string indices
```

Of course, while writing this question, I had a sudden realization: what about `match()`? Again assuming the file first in the question and:

```
vim9script

def pnd2test#Invoke()
    echoerr match(getline('.'), 'å')
enddef
```

the result is 4. This means match() also results in legacy indices. Here's an expanded example:

File:

```
æøå this is a unicode line
```

Code:

```
vim9script

def pnd2test#Invoke()
    echoerr getline('.')[match(getline('.'), 'å')]
enddef
```

Returns `t`, not `å`. Just for the record, this isn't a problem caused by `getline()`. As observed earlier, `getline('.')[2]` does give the right results. This also results in `t` instead of `å`:

```
def pnd2test#Invoke()
    var x: string = 'æøå t'
    echoerr x[match(x, 'å')]
enddef
```

This in turn kinda expands the problem: several of the vimscript functions return indices that are incompatible with vimscript strings. This of course is my question: when there are several functions returning incompatible indices, how do I in vim9 do any operations on strings containing unicode when using these types of functions?

Comment: Is [`charcol('.')`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#charcol%28%29) what you're looking for? It works similarly to `col('.')` but returns the index of the Unicode character, not the byte position.

Comment: In part, but not entirely. Fortunately, the docs include byteidx() and charidx() (that I of course managed to miss when reading col() docs), which should be enough to let be convert between systems and access strings properly. charcol should fix the col issue, and byteidx and charidx should be able to work around compatibility with other functions.

Comment: Feel free to post a self answer with what solved the issue in full for you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden) nudged me in the right direction [in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30984/how-do-i-work-with-vim9-and-unicode#comment56235_30984).

`charcol('.')` works around pure access based on the current cursor position, meaning `line[charcol('.') - 1]` returns the correct character for the current column, at least for two-byte characters. I'm still not entirely sure how far the unicode strings in vim9 go, so it might be that it'll fail to retrieve characters consisting of more bytes. Not sure how `charcol()` works with those, but for my purpose, it's good enough.

That alone doesn't help with `match()` or other functions, though. However, the nudge in the comment also helped me find two other functions that are extremely useful: `charidx()` and `byteidx()`. `match()` itself still takes the start position in bytes and not characters, which means any limits relative to the cursor position should still use `col()`.

`byteidx()` is not as useful for cursor-related access (we already have `col()`, so taking the output from `charcol()` and using it for `byteidx()` is just `col()` with extra steps), but it can be used to convert a char position into a byte position. This is extremely useful if there's a char index that's calculated in some other way. Again, this is largely useful for the `start` parameter of `match()`, or similar arguments for other functions that take a position in bytes rather than in characters, and you're sitting there with a character position.

With `charidx()` though, we can convert the output of `match()` into a character position that can be used to re-index a string. Taking the example `getline('.')[match(getline('.'), 'å')]` from the question:

```
getline('.')[charidx(getline('.'), match(getline('.'), 'å'))]
```

(Of course, I don't recommend three calls to `getline()` when one is enough, but for the sake of testing and demonstration, this works fine)

Assuming usage on the file `æøå t`, the code returns `å` instead of `t`, in spite of `match()` returning the wrong position.

Just for the sake of including an example of it, assuming you have a character position, this is how it's converted back to a byte position (test file: æøåæøå)

```
vim9script

def pndtest#Invoke()
    echoerr charidx(getline('.'),
        match(getline('.'), 'å', byteidx(getline('.'), charcol('.')))
    )
enddef
```

Of course, `byteidx(getline('.'), charcol('.'))` is completely redundant (because it's `col('.')` with extra steps), but it demonstrates how positions can be converted from chars, into bytes, and finally back into chars for reuse in a string. The number returned by `charidx` could here be used to index a string, regardless of whether that string is the result of `getline('.')` or not.

This isn't elegant though, but it does the trick at converting between the two index types. In an optimal world, we wouldn't need to convert between the two for string compatibility, but here we are.

**TL;DR:** use `charidx()` to convert to the format used by vim9 strings, and `byteidx()` to convert from the format used by vim9 strings. `charcol()` can be used to get the current cursor position in a way that's directly usable by strings without conversion first.

---

And finally, a tiny list of alternatives to broken functions to avoid `charidx()` and `byteidx()` where conversion isn't needed, such as for accessing strings directly in vim9:

- `col()` -> `charcol()`
- `len(str)` -> `len(split(str, '\zs'))` (split strings by characters, return the length of the split (meaning the character count) instead of the byte count - not performance tested)

---

It's also worth noting that a few of the functions here have applications in regular vimscript as well, especially if you need to operate on characters instead of bytes. One notable difference is that there's different conversions and systems for accessing strings by characters in regular vimscript compared to vim9. However, that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for posting such a detailed answer!!!